# Can I unlock Dragon Armor, Roxas Outfit and Axel Outfit in Dragon Quest IX? How?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

[This link](http://mycheats.1up.com/list/cheat/3155836/dragon_quest_ix__sentinels_of_the_starry_skies/nintendo_ds) says that I can unlock these sets of armor by killing 100 Metal Slimes.

- Is this true?  I would have expected to find more than just the one reference to this unlockable.
- Is there something else I have to do after killing the Metal Slimes?
- Is it just the plain old Metal Slimes in the Quarantomb, or any Slime which is also Metal?

Comment: I have killed well over 100 plain old Metal Slimes, and have not received any new equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using the information at the provided link.

I have killed well over 100 plain old metal slimes (and quite a few LMS, MKS and PKJ too).  I have received no special outfits.

I suspect that there is no way to do this.  [As always, if you have a different answer, post it.  ;)  ]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a phony "cheat" to me. The following guides have no mention of any sort of KH related armor:

Alchemy Recipe Guide:
http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/937281-dragon-quest-ix-sentinels-of-the-starry-skies/faqs/60451

Alchemy Item List:
http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/937281-dragon-quest-ix-sentinels-of-the-starry-skies/faqs/60440

Item Location Guide:
http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/937281-dragon-quest-ix-sentinels-of-the-starry-skies/faqs/60679

Item Farming Guide:
http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/937281-dragon-quest-ix-sentinels-of-the-starry-skies/faqs/60562

Safe to assume there's no way of obtaining those items ;).